# Solr Searchbox with Auto-complete / Suggestion?

Tags: search, drop-down-menu, autocomplete, solr, autosuggest

To work with Solr, I need my searchbox to be suggesting whenever user type.. with a dropdown menu. How can i get it done? Any existing example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://blog.trifork.com/2012/02/15/different-ways-to-make-auto-suggestions-with-solr/) is an article I wrote about different ways to make auto suggestions and how to make the right choice. If you want something even more advanced and flexible there is [this other article](http://www.cominvent.com/2012/01/25/super-flexible-autocomplete-with-solr/), which contains an example as well.

Comment: The article is quite old! I have updated the link though as the blogpost has been moved a couple of times meanwhile ;) thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Suggester component - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Suggester/

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of providing autosuggest capabilities.

*Single term suggestion*

This method looks for the first letter, then the first word in a phrase, a search for “men’s shirts” must begin with “m,” then “men’s,” to bring up “men’s shirts” as a response.

This could be done by using following field type and querying with `my little po*`

```
<fieldType name="suggestion_text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
       <analyzer>
          <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
       </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

*Multiterm unordered suggestions*

This autocomplete method recognizes “shirts” as part of the phrase, like “men’s shirts,” and suggests it to the customer along with “women’s shirts,” “work shirts,” and other phrases that contain “men’s.”

This one could be done by using following field type and querying with `my AND little AND po*`

```
<fieldType name="prefix_text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
   </analyzer>

</fieldType>
```

*Multiterm ordered suggestions*

The third method matches everything that contains a subphrase of the complete phrase as long as it’s in the correct order, i.e. “men’s shir,” but not “shirts me.”

Solr doesn’t have built-in features to generate this, but we can implement our own token filter. For more information on this and previous implementation (as well as complete information) - take a look at this [blog post](https://blog.griddynamics.com/implementing-autocomplete-with-solr)